# Need to fix JQuery Script to force 'href' to CTRL+Click from a click

Tags: html, jquery

I have fudged this script together to a get a couple of href's for force new/black page on a click, because our PDF docs will not full open open from our CMS/LMS site. CTRL+click work but not all our student know that. Therefor, I need to script it so they can just clik on the link(image).

'.pdf-new' is the class id for the href link on the images.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".pdf-new").on("click", function(){
            $(this).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
        });
    });

<a class="pdf-new" href="Dominic_Subject_Handbook_Final2-GLS-23-002.pdf" target="_blank" type="pdf">
<img id="subject-hb" src="Images/Screenshot_2021-Subject-Handbook.png" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: <a class="pdf-new" href="Dominic_Subject_Handbook_Final2-GLS-23-002.pdf" target="_blank" type="pdf">
<img id="subject-hb" src="Images/Screenshot_2021-Subject-Handbook.png" alt=""></a>

Comment: I am still trying to solve this code. I do need the "MouseEvent" to get the adition CTRL Key on click.

Answer (score 0):

No need to deal with mouse events when you can just modify the existing links to have a `target="_blank"` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pdf-new').attr( 'target', '_blank' );
});
```

Then the clicks will open in new tab.

Comment: the target="_blank" is already in the href. however, this still does not load the pdf, even though it is open in a new tab (looks like it is loaded but remains a blank page)